# Way to include many images into Flutter app

Tags: flutter, mobile

I have a trivia game which has about 300 images(hd and sd) that need to included in game. Is there a quick way to embed them into my game instead of the following?

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - icons/heart.png
```

In this way, it will takes 500 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to list each of your images; it's enough to add the folder to assets:

```
flutter:
  assets:
      - assets/
```

And then you can just load the image:

```
Image.asset('assets/filename.jpg');
```

The above comments are suggesting to keep the images in the cloud. I think - if your application will use some of the images for a single user (depending on what user does), this makes sense. But if all users will use all images; then you will end up downloading all those images anyway; still using up all the space - plus having to download them when needed. The advantage might be - you would be able to change the images without users having to install the new version.

The code above I used in a card game I did - and each user will be using all 50+ images I had in the assets - so there was no reason to store them in the cloud.

Comment: You would have to download them, but they would be stored in memory during the lifetime of the app. They would not take up persistent storage unless you chose to cache them. 300 images could increase an app's size by nearly a gigabyte depending on the images.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store all the images in assets folder. 500 is a huge count. Store it in Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage and retrieve images using Flutter network.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image

Ex: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9')